# why tcl expect exit unexpectly?

Tags: windows, tcl, exit, expect

On Windows, I tested a tcl expect script as followed:

```
package require Expect
spawn "cmd.exe"
expect ">"
send "echo hello world\r"
```

But the output printed "`F:\Workspace\>`", then it exited. 
Of cource, I expect that it executes "`echo hello world`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the way Expect for Windows works (it uses a special debugging mode) there are certain programs which can't be captured; telnet.exe is one, and cmd.exe could well be another. (The executables concerned have the system bit set in their file flags IIRC.)

Fortunately, the programs that this causes problems for are usually the ones that you don't actually *need* to automate with Expect. Tcl is quite capable of talking to other machines directly (by opening a [`socket`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/socket.htm)) and cmd is both often unneeded and (in the other cases) easy to automate by just using the [`exec`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm) command. If this was just a test that was a proxy for your *real* automation, don't worry too much for now; try to automate the real program, though just do something simple (like exit cleanly) to start out with and build up from there.

Comment: FTP is another program that you don't need to use Expect for; there's a perfectly adequate FTP client in Tcllib (called `ftp`, miraculously!)

Answer (score 0):

It might be better if you tell me the problem you're really trying to solve. But anyway, you just need to type
`echo hello world` 
instead of

```
send "echo hello world\r"
```

to get the result you require.

cheers
Brian

Comment: I don't know why somebody gave me -1. The problems with Expect on Windows are well known. That's why I asked the original questioner what problem he was really trying to solve. In the meantime, the solution I gave actually does work i.e if you take his code and replace the `send` line with `echo hello world`, it does what he asked for i.e. "I expect that it executes "echo hello world""

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I guess the reason is you didn't mark the fact that the questioner is (probably) *really* about to work with some other application and was using CMD.EXE as something to experiment with. (After all, you wouldn't actually bother to automate CMD like that in production; it doesn't need it!) That means that what you suggested was exactly unhelpful; contrast with my answer which pointed out what the problem probably was (the system bit on CMD is magical) and, I hope, encouraged the questioner to try it with their real app.

Comment: In other words, when answering a question you've got to think about why the other person is asking it and express the answer that is helpful to them in a way that they can understand and accept. It takes plenty of practice.